# Members table with one instead of three unique fields

Tags: mysql, user-registration

In almost each code example by creating mysql joinUs table, there is the code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` text, //unique
`email` text, //unique
`pass` text,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
```

So, if username and/or email is set as unique, what is then the purpose of id field?
Can I simply set username as primary key and exclude the id from the table?

Comment: Leave it as an id. If you have other tables (like a comments or a posts table) having the userID as the reference will be easier, better, and faster than using the username. (what happens if the user wants to change their username, for example?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id is a nice convention because it will never change. That lets other tables reference users via their id, and enables you to let users change their usernames and emails. Having said that, yes, you could use username as a primary key.

Comment: Thanks, Lyn. I will trace the things once more, but it seems - I'll do so.

Comment: Also using names/numbers that 'should be' unique as primary keys has a tendency to come around and bite you when your customer comes one day and says 'i need to have multiple users with the same e-mail'.

Comment: Multiple users with the same mail ?  What could be the point of that scenatio ? Why ?

Comment: @Alegro The same as having 2 shipments with the same shipment number (speaking from experience here). Your customer says so and you can't talk him out of it ... Edit: and yes, we also have multiple users with the same email, I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks, Vatev. I just want to make the things logical and simple. But I believe that experience is often - outside of concepts.